# Как указать поисковому роботу новую версию страницы без 301 редиректа

Tags: seo, robots.txt, meta

Есть некий онлайн-инструмент, которым пользуются люди. Я сделал новую версию этого инструмента и разместил его по другому адресу. Как указать поисковым роботам, без редиректа, что это новая версия страницы и нужно перенести вес со старой на неё?

Делать редирект не предоставляется (по крайней мере пока) возможным, в силу того, что старый вариант инструмента должен продолжать работать, так как новый вариант может быть не совместим с некоторыми старыми браузерами.

Может есть варианты использовать `robots.txt` или `<meta>`?

Answer (score 1):

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_301_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0_HTTP

Тут описано.
Запрос клиента:

```
GET /index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.org
```

Ответ сервера:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently 
Location: http://www.example.org/index.asp
```

Comment: В этом случае будет происходить редирект, а он мне не нужен! Более правильно (ранее я не так задавал запросы) порыскав в интернете, я нашёл инфу по `<meta name="url">`, `<link rel="canonical">` и HTTP-заголовок `Link` ... Осталось только попробовать на практике.

Comment: да, что-то я невнимательно прочитал вопрос, извините.